# Write a query to display the field in both ascending order and descending order

Tags: sql-server

I have encountered this in an interview. The table design contains a single field of integer value. Write a query to display the field in both ascending order and descending order

Comment: do you come up with something?

Comment: Post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Read about `ORDER BY` clause here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: Question looks interesting but we need more information on your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(N INT)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);

WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn_a = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N ASC),
        rn_d = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N DESC)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT 
    Ascending = a.N, 
    Descending = b.N
FROM Cte a
INNER JOIN Cte b
    ON b.rn_d = a.rn_a

DROP TABLE tbl
```

**RESULT**

```
Ascending   Descending
----------- -----------
1           10
2           9
3           8
4           7
5           6
6           5
7           4
8           3
9           2
10          1
```

Comment: Nope. I believe there is no `ROW_NUMBER` function in MySql.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table named `tbl` with column name `value` of type `int` then use `Order by` clause to get ascending and descending values

like this for ascending order:

```
SELECT value FROM tbl ORDER BY value ASC
```

and for descending order:

```
SELECT value FROM tbl ORDER BY value DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.num,b.num from 
(select a.num, row_number() over (order by num) as rnum  from nums a) a
join (select a.num, row_number() over (order by num desc) as rnum  from nums a) b on a.rnum = b.rnum;
```